# What is the reason behind the segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm unable to debug the following code in any debugger as it shows, "During startup program ended with segmentation fault SIGEGV"

This is code to find whether is a Graph is Bipartite or Not.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ll long long

ll queue[1000000000];
ll last=0;
ll top=0;

int qempty()
{
    if(top==last) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

void emptyq()
{
    top=0;
    last=0;
}
void enqueue(long long x)
{
    queue[top++] = x;
}
void dequeue()
{
    queue[last++];
}
```

Here I defined the queue. And the following are the functions for Graph.

```
struct node
{
    ll vertex;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* createNode(ll v)
{
    struct node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->vertex = v;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    return newnode;
}

struct Graph
{
    ll numVertices;
    struct node** adjLists;
};

struct Graph *createG (ll vertices)
{
    struct Graph *G = malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    G->numVertices = vertices;
    G->adjLists = malloc(vertices*sizeof(struct node*));
    for(int i=0;i<vertices;i++) G->adjLists[i]=NULL;
    return G;
}

void add(struct Graph* G, ll src, ll dest)
{
    struct node* newnode = createNode(dest);
    newnode->next = G->adjLists[src];
    G->adjLists[src] = newnode;

    newnode = createNode(src);
    newnode->next = G->adjLists[dest];
    G->adjLists[dest] = newnode;

}
```

This is the function for checking the edges between same layer of Breadth First Search.

```
ll BU(struct Graph *G, ll src, ll *color)
{ 
    color[src] = 1;
    emptyq();
    enqueue(src);
    while (qempty); 
    { 
        ll u = queue[last];
        dequeue;
        struct node *y = G->adjLists[u];
        while(y)
        { 
            if(color[y->vertex]==-1)
            { 
                color[y->vertex] = 1-color[u]; 
                enqueue(y->vertex);
            } 
            else if (color[y->vertex] == color[u]) return 0;

            y=y->next;
        }
    } 
    return 1; 

}

ll B(struct Graph *G) 
{ 
    ll x = G->numVertices;
    ll *color = malloc(x*sizeof(long long));
    for (ll i = 0; i < x; ++i) color[i] = -1; 

    for (ll i = 0; i < x; i++) 
    if (color[i] == -1) 
        if (BU(G,i,color)==0) 
        return 0; 

    else  return 1; 
}
```

This is the main Function. I added a breakpoint at the very first line of main function but it refused to continue.

```
int main()
{
    ll t;
    scanf("%lld",&t);
    printf("%lld",t);
    while(t--)
    {
        ll V,E;
        scanf("%lld %lld",&V,&E);
        printf("%lld %lld",V,E);
        struct Graph *G = createG(V);
        while(E--)
        {
            ll x,y;
            scanf("%lld %lld",&x,&y);
            add(G,x,y);
        }
        if(B(G)==1) printf("Yes\n");
        else printf("No\n");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ll queue[1000000000];` even if your machine has 7.4 GB of memory just lying around, it probably won't be able to allocate that much in one go.

Comment: Aside: you should `#include <stdio.h>` too.

Comment: It is as @Blaze said but also, it's a stack allocation and the stack is generally limited to at most 8MB (depends on the system).

Comment: @mwk it's a static allocation. The MSVC I use won't allow more than about 2Gb memory in total, whether static or dynamic.

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  amongst other things, it is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`  to expose the prototypes for functions: `scanf()`. `printf()`  etc etc

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion  -pedantic -std=gnuu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same putout.

Comment: OT: regarding: `#define ll long long`  This is a very bad idea.  At best such should be avoided, and if used should be: `typedef long long ll;`

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%lld %lld",&V,&E);`  When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value ( not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In the current case, any returned value other than 2 indicates an error occurred..  In the case of `scanf("%lld",&t);` any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.

Comment: OT: regarding: `ll *color = malloc(x*sizeof(long long));` when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()`, `calloc()`, and/or `realloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "malloc failed" )` so both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `while (qempty); `  this results in looking at the address of: `qempty` which will always evaluate to `true`.  Probably not what you want.  Perhaps you meant: `while( qempty() )`

Comment: regarding: `while (qempty);`  is there some other thread that changes the result?  If not then this loop will never get beyond this one statement.  At a minimum suggest writing this as: `while (qempty())`  Notice no trailing semicolon

Comment: regarding: `dequeue;`   What is this expected to do?  There is no function: `dequeue();` in the posted code.

Comment: regarding: `for (ll i = 0; i < x; i++) 
    if (color[i] == -1) 
        if (BU(G,i,color)==0) 
        return 0; 

    else  return 1;`   which `if()` does the `else` belong to?  Always use braces suggest: `for (ll i = 0; i < x; i++)  {  if (color[i] == -1) { if (BU(G,i,color)==0)  { return 0; }  else  { return 1; } }`  However, if I have 'guessed' correctly as to what you meant, then the `for()` loop will only be executed once.

Comment: in function; `B(struct Graph *G)`  there is a execution path that does not contain a `return value` statement.  Please post code that cleanly compiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to reduce the size of this:

```
ll queue[1000000000];
```

to a more reasonable value, say `1024`.

Answer (score 0):

The maximal size of statically allocated data of a process is typically small. It is an inherent problem of the address space mapping, the exact size if system-dependent but in practice don't expect more than some megabytes.

You can do one of these:

- allocate the memory dynamically
- use a lesser static memory block
- you can change your - similarly highly platform-dependent - settings which increase the initial static data size.